# Get API I got two type of response Response1 is List of Object and another is only object, how to handle that in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing

Get API I got two type of response Response1 is List of Object and another is only object, how to handle that in flutter?

Response1

```
{ 
          "result":   [
              {
                
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Response List 1",
                "body": "Response List 1 body"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Response List 2",
                "body": "Response List 2 body"
              }
        ]
        }
```

Response2

```
      {
          "result": {
                
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Response Object",
                "body": "Response Object body"
              },
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for that. My solution is working if your responses **result** is object either list only.

```
class ResponseModel {
  List<Result>? result;

  ResponseModel({this.result});

  ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['result'] != null) {
      result = <Result>[];
      try {
        json['result'].forEach((v) {
          result!.add(Result.fromJson(v));
        });
      } catch (e) {
        result!.add(Result.fromJson(json['result']));
      }
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (result != null) {
      try {
        data['result'] = result!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
      } catch (e){
        data['result'] = result!.toList();
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Result {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? body;

  Result({this.id, this.title, this.body});

  Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['body'] = body;
    return data;
  }
}
```

output is

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      "result": [
        {"id": 1, "title": "Response List 1", "body": "Response List 1 body"},
        {"id": 2, "title": "Response List 2", "body": "Response List 2 body"}
      ]
    };

print(ResponseModel.fromJson(map).result?.length); //2
```

- 

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
  "result": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Response Object",
    "body": "Response Object body",
  }
};

print(ResponseModel.fromJson(map).result?.length); //1
```